# GeoServer: Stores and Layers migration issue

Tags: geoserver

I have copied workspaces and styles from data_dir folder of one GeoServer to another in order to migrate data. Then restarted GeoServer and workspaces and styles appeared in the new server. But no Stores and Layers.

I have found in similar question that there is a trick needs to be done with datastore.xml file to make Stores and Layers also migrated.

[How to migrate a specific workspace, store and layer in Geoserver](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/how-to-migrate-a-specific-workspace-store-and-layer-in-geoserver)

[image]

I have deleted all content from this tag and this made a trick. Store and Published layers have appeared.

**Is it secure to delete this tag? What does it mean when I delete it?**

[image]

Comment: You need to copy the whole data directory not bits of it.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But unfortunately, I have data from three geoservers, that I need to migrate into one. Therefore, I can use just one data_dir folder and restore data partially from other two... what to do in this case?

Comment: and [we told you](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/443612/merge-geoservers) it can't be done that way, unless the workspace is **isolated**. The password is not relevant to your issue (that was for 2.7.x to 2.9.x).